# Two join tables. How to administer?

Tags: silverstripe

I have this relationship in my SS3 project:

- Restaurant many_many Cuisine
- Cuisine many_many SubCuisine

Seems simple enough but I can't seem to find any way to administer it.  Tried GridField and Listbox. Is this a limitation of SilverStripe perhaps?

Thanks for any leads!
Wilson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After our conversation on IRC we came up with the following alternative solution, which I will post here for the record.

This solution is quiet similar to the original answer, with the difference, that there is an additional object that handles the relation between `Restaurant` and `Cuisine`.

File: Restaurant.php

```
/**
 * @method ManyManyList RestaurantCuisines
 */
class Restaurant extends Page {
    private static $many_many = array(
        'RestaurantCuisines' => 'RestaurantCuisine',
    );

    /**
     * @return FieldList
     */
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $return = parent::getCMSFields();
        $return->addFieldToTab('Root', Tab::create('Cuisines', 'The Cuisines'));
        $return->addFieldToTab(
            'Root.Cuisines',
            GridField::create(
                'RestaurantCuisines',
                'The Cuisines this Restaurant offers',
                $this->RestaurantCuisines(),
                GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
            )
        );
        return $return;
    }
}

class Restaurant_Controller extends Page_Controller {
}
```

File: RestaurantCuisine.php

```
/**
 * @property int CuisineID
 * @method Cuisine Cuisine
 * @method ManyManyList SubCuisines
 */
class RestaurantCuisine extends DataObject {
    private static $has_one = array(
        'Cuisine' => 'Cuisine',
    );
    private static $many_many = array(
        'SubCuisines' => 'SubCuisine',
    );
    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'getTitle' => 'Title'
    );
    public function getCMSFields() {
        if ($this->isInDB()) {
            $grid = GridField::create(
                'SubCuisines',
                'The Sub Cuisines of this Cuisines',
                $this->SubCuisines(),
                GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create()
            );
        } else {
            // because this record is not saved to the DB yet, we have no ID, without ID there can be no many_many relation
            $grid = ReadonlyField::create('SubCuisines', '', 'Sub Cuisines can be added after creating');
        }
        return FieldList::create(array(
            DropdownField::create('CuisineID', 'Select a Cuisine', Cuisine::get()->map()),
            $grid
        ));
    }
    /**
     * overwrite getTitle and return title of Cuisine to have a nice text to display instead of the ID when displaying the save message
     */
    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->Cuisine() && $this->Cuisine()->exists() ? $this->Cuisine()->Title : parent::getTitle();
    }
}
```

File: Cuisine.php

```
/**
 * @property string Title
 */
class Cuisine extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(255)',
    );

    /**
     * @return FieldList
     */
    public function getCMSFields() {
        return FieldList::create(array(
            TextField::create('Title', 'Name of Cuisine'),
        ));
    }
}
```

File: SubCuisine.php

```
/**
 * @property string Title
 */
class SubCuisine extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(255)',
    );

    /**
     * @return FieldList
     */
    public function getCMSFields() {
        return FieldList::create(array(
            TextField::create('Title', 'Name of Cuisine'),
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GridField is the perfect tool to manage this kind of data structure, I do it on a daily bases.

Because of your topic I feel the need to also mention this: it doesn't join here (ok, yes the ORM does joins, but not Restaurant & Cuisine & SubCuisine).
What the below example will do:

- on a single  `Restaurant` it will display a list (GridField) of `Cuisine`s, where you can create new ones or attach existing ones.
- on a single `Cuisine` it will display a list (GridField) of `SubCuisine`s, where you can create new ones or attach existing ones.

(I am assuming that `Restaurant` is a `Page`, but it works just as well if its a normal `DataObject`)

---

File `Restaurant.php`:

```
/**
 * @method ManyManyList Cuisines
 */
class Restaurant extends Page {
    private static $many_many = array(
        'Cuisines' => 'Cuisine',
    );

    /**
     * @return FieldList
     */
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $return = parent::getCMSFields();
        $return->addFieldToTab('Root', Tab::create('Cuisines', 'The Cuisines'));
        $return->addFieldToTab(
            'Root.Cuisines',
            GridField::create(
                'Cuisines',
                'The Cuisines this Restaurant offers',
                $this->Cuisines(),
                GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create()
            )
        );
        return $return;
    }
}

class Restaurant_Controller extends Page_Controller {
}
```

File `Cuisine.php`:

```
/**
 * @property string Title
 * @method ManyManyList SubCuisines
 */
class Cuisine extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(255)',
    );
    private static $many_many = array(
        'SubCuisines' => 'SubCuisine',
    );

    /**
     * @return FieldList
     */
    public function getCMSFields() {
        if ($this->isInDB()) {
            $grid = GridField::create(
                'SubCuisines',
                'The Sub Cuisines of this Cuisines',
                $this->SubCuisines(),
                GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create()
            );
        } else {
            // because this record is not saved to the DB yet, we have no ID, without ID there can be no many_many relation
            $grid = ReadonlyField::create('SubCuisines', '', 'Sub Cuisines can be added after creating');
        }
        return FieldList::create(array(
            TextField::create('Title', 'Name of Cuisine'),
            $grid,
        ));
    }
}
```

File `SubCuisine.php`:

```
/**
 * @property string Title
 */
class SubCuisine extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(255)',
    );

    /**
     * @return FieldList
     */
    public function getCMSFields() {
        return FieldList::create(array(
            TextField::create('Title', 'Name of Cuisine'),
        ));
    }
}
```

File `Restaurant.ss` (template):

```
<h1>Restaurant: $Title</h1>
<% if $Cuisines %>
    <h2>Cuisines</h2>
    <ol>
        <% loop $Cuisines %>
            <li>
                <h3>$Title</h3>
                <% if $SubCuisines %>
                    <h4>Sub Cuisines:</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <% loop $SubCuisines %>
                            <li>
                                <h5>$Title</h5>
                            </li>
                        <% end_loop %>
                    </ul>
                <% end_if %>
            </li>
        <% end_loop %>
    </ol>
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: Thanks Zauberfisch!  I was working down a much more complicated route.  Will try this now. So it doesn't create duplicate records in the SubCuisine table?

Comment: it will create multiple records if you use the create button. however if you use a `GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor` there is not only a create button, there is also a "link existing" field, which allows you to search existing records and link one of them instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks Zauberfisch. This is a nice solution but in my case, I need the SubCuisines to not always be attached to the same parent Cuisine in every case.  So, for example, Restaurant1 -> Japanese -> Fusion.  Restaurant2 -> Chinese -> Fusion.  Seems like there has to be another join table of Restaurant_Cuisines_SubCuisines.  Unless I'm missing something.  Thoughts?

Comment: I think I need to create a Restaurant_Cuisines DataObject even though SS has already created the table, so that SubCuisine can have many_many relationship to it.

Comment: so Cuisines might have different SubCuisines for each restaurant? then it would probably be best to make Restaurant has_many Cuisines instead of many_many (so Cuisine has_one Restaurant). This means that you have to recreate the Cuisines for each restaurant though.